# Cannot find symbol when compiling my code

Tags: java

I have some Java code:

```
public class Car 
{ 
    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(int newYearModel, String newMake)
    {
        yearModel = newYearModel;
        make = newMake;
        speed = 0;
    }
    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }
    public void accelerate()
    {
        speed += 5; 
    }
}
```

I try to compile and run this specific program and I get this error:

```
CarClient.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
      myCar.accelerateSpeed(speed);
                          ^
  symbol:   variable speed
  location: class CarClient
```

What does `error: cannot find symbol` mean?

Comment: It means you didn't define the method, or you didn't define a variable.  The solution is to define the method `accelerateSpeed(...)` , or to define the variable `speed` you are passing into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `accelerateSpeed(speed)` but the only method you have implemented is `accelerate()` which takes no parameters. Similarly, you're trying to call `brakeSpeed(speed)` but have only implemented `brake()` with no parameters. Either implement the functions you're trying to call, or change the names of the functions you already have implemented.

Comment: so in that regard just remove the speed from both the accelerate and brake parameters then to run the program properly.

Comment: In your code, when you call `accelerateSpeed(speed)`, change it to just `accelerate()` with no reference to `speed`. The same goes for `brakeSpeed(speed)` and `brake()`

Comment: I missed one small part in the program to add, I want my program to double up or slow down the speed at it's going with, going to update it just in a second. I am sorry for not adding that in, that was suppose to be part of just help clear it out.

Comment: added the part I was missing from earlier, sorry for the error.

Answer (score 1):

There's no method named "breakSpeed" or "accelerateSpeed" that I can see; the compiler agrees with me.

I think you mean "brake" and "accelerate".

Comment: Yes, so I would just change brakespeed and acceleratespeed, to simply brake and accelerate respectively then, because I want my client class to call on my service class of brake and accelerate respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your `accelerate()` declaration in the `Car` class does not accept an argument - yet you called `accelerateSpeed(speed)` in `main()`.